# Undefined index: id, unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, laravel

I am messing about with CSV files inside a console command for laravel. I am aware there are libraries for importing CSV files, however i have came across a strange undefined index error i am hoping someone may have more information about. I can achieve what i need without this column, but i am curious as to why this error is occurring.

```php
public function handle()
    {
        $file = Storage::disk('local')->get('upload.csv');

        $lines = explode("\r\n", $file);

        $keys = [];

        foreach ($lines as $key => $line)
        {

            $outputLine = [];

            if($key == 0)
            {
                // Get header columns
                $keys = str_getcsv($line); continue;
            }

            // Get row contents
            $items = str_getcsv($line);

            foreach ($items as $k => $item)
            {
                // Rename keys to match headers
                $outputLine[$keys[$k]] = $item;
            }
                // try to access $outputLine['id']
                // error: Undefined Index: id

            $csv[$key] = $outputLine;
        }

    }
```

However output of `$csv[$key]`  clearly shows the key ['id'] for all entries in the csv. Trying to access here also throws the same issue. Accessing any other arbitrary key in the array works fine. It is always the first key, regardless of name.

UPDATE: Providing example of CSV import

```
id,name,email,membership_id
1,John,John@example.com,1
2,Jane,Jane@example.com,2
3,Brian,Brian@example.com,3
```

UPDATE 2: Providing dump of $items

```
array:4 [
  0 => "1"
  1 => "John"
  2 => "john@example.com"
  3 => "1"
]
array:4 [
  0 => "2"
  1 => "Jane"
  2 => "jane@example.com"
  3 => "2"
]
array:4 [
  0 => "3"
  1 => "Brian"
  2 => "brian@example.com"
  3 => "3"
]
array:4 [
  0 => "4"
  1 => "Adam"
  2 => "adam@example.com"
  3 => "4"
]
array:4 [
  0 => "5"
  1 => "Frank"
  2 => "frank@example.com"
  3 => "5"
]
array:4 [
  0 => "6"
  1 => "Phil"
  2 => "phil@example.com"
  3 => "6"
]
```

DUMP OF `$outputLine`

```
array:4 [
  "id" => "1"
  "name" => "John"
  "email" => "john@example.com"
  "membership_id" => "1"
]
array:4 [
  "id" => "2"
  "name" => "Jane"
  "email" => "jane@example.com"
  "membership_id" => "2"
]
array:4 [
  "id" => "3"
  "name" => "Brian"
  "email" => "brian@example.com"
  "membership_id" => "3"
]
array:4 [
  "id" => "4"
  "name" => "Adam"
  "email" => "adam@example.com"
  "membership_id" => "4"
]
array:4 [
  "id" => "5"
  "name" => "Frank"
  "email" => "frank@example.com"
  "membership_id" => "5"
]
array:4 [
  "id" => "6"
  "name" => "Phil"
  "email" => "phil@example.com"
  "membership_id" => "6"
]
```

Comment: How does that CSV file look like? Perhaps you're using different delimiters?

Comment: I have provided a simplified sample of the CSV.

Comment: Thanks. Also, it could be helpful if you could provide a dump before `foreach ($items as $k => $item)` loop. What do you get from `var_dump($keys, $items);`?

Comment: I have added dumps as an edit

Comment: Thanks. Seems good. Are you sure you're trying to access `$outputLine['id']` after this `foreach ($items as $k => $item)`?

Comment: Yep, even if i grab ```$csv``` and loop back through and try to access 'id' or any other key which is key 0 in the chain it is not defined. But if i reference, 'name', 'email', etc it works absolutely fine.

Comment: How are you trying to access this? If you do `$csv['id']` it will not work but `$csv[1]['id']` should (since 0 is omitted since that's the header row). Take a look at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cd001a39e859381ee2e72ff70c9e24e3f1a54f7

Comment: i am accessing it either before the ```$csv``` variable is created, as ```$outputLine['id']```, or i am accessing later as a loop through ```$csv```

Comment: If you try to access `$outputLine['id']` right after that loop (and before `$csv[$key] = $outputLine;` assignment) it works perfectly. Maybe you could provide a complete script like apokryfos did?

Comment: This is just it, It should work perfectly. Could it perhaps be the format of the specific csv? could it be corrupt?

Comment: It could be. Maybe unprintable character? The snippet you gave us works as expected (but we test it as "string"). Where did you get that file from? Maybe try with a new one, create it manually.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the input given. Sidenote. `\r\n` may not always be the correct delimiter. For windows it's `\r\n` for Unix/Linux/newer MacOS it's `\n` and for older MacOS it's `\r` . `PHP_EOL` should contain the correct one based on the OS in theory. (In practice I think nowadays it's just `\n` )

Comment: That's it!  changing just to ```\n``` has resolved the issue, which is strange as ```\r\n``` are both present if you print a line before converting to an array. Thank you for your help. If you put this into an answer i can accept.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you used the default delimiter `,` in your CSV

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Try setting the right one depending on what you have in your input file

```
str_getcsv($line, ';') // example with ';' delimiter
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, sorry i should have provided a snippet of my CSV, the CSV is indeed comma delimited.